# Ionic ERROR: version.json FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to *ionic*. Can anyone please help me solve the following error:

> [WARN] Error with .\WWW\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying .\bower .json

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: There might be a bug with your current setup check the link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2656

Comment: version.json file is not getting created ... is there any command for that ?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, just run the following within the ionic repo:

`rm -rf resources/android`

`ionic cordova resources`